# ElasticSearch: Filter by distinct count during aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation

The following query returns distinct Ids in order by largest distinct count of Ids. What I would like to do is **"include only those IDs for which total number of documents is less than 2000"**

```
{
  "size": "0",
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2020-10-20T00:00:00",
        "lt": "2020-10-21T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Id.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I tried adding filter by 'doc_count' but that didn't help. How do I do this?

Comment: Give me some time please. Just waking up. Thanks.

Comment: okay, no problem 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can filter the buckets using [bucket_selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation)**

> Bucket Selector Aggregation is a parent pipeline aggregation which executes a script which determines
> whether the current bucket will be retained in the parent multi-bucket
> aggregation.

```
{
  "size": "0",
  "query": {
    "range": {
      "@timestamp": {
        "gte": "2020-10-20T00:00:00",
        "lt": "2020-10-21T00:00:00"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "Id.keyword",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "count_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "values": "_count"
            },
            "script": "params.values < 2000"   <-- note this
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This didnt' work for me. What does 'note this' mean? Was I supposed to change anything. I used it "as is".

Comment: @DilTeam `note this` was just to point out to the bucket selector aggregation in the query. Are you getting any error when running the above search query? I tried it locally also, and it is working fine

Comment: Wait. Count will be applied only with the "range" of dates, right? Hmm... this might be working then. Let me see.